# Sitecore web forms for marketers send email message not working

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, web-forms-for-marketers

I have a WFFM in my application which sends a thank you email after registration in my site. I have changed some email body text and it stopped working not sure why. Is there any way to check the issue or upload the template again?

Comment: Did you change ONLY the email text or also the recipient(s)? Or anything else? To start resolving: check the logs of the application and the mailserver you are using (to verify if the mail is not stopped there)

Comment: Which version of Sitecore and WFFM module?

Answer (score 1):

The question is very light on details but on WFFM 8.0 this is a known bug, if you check the logs then the following error will be present:

```
Exception: System.FormatException 
Message: The specified string is not in the form required for an e-mail address.
```

The problem is due to a bug in the Mail Message editor, which causes any dynamic user input fields in the TO, FROM or CC fields to be incorrectly encoded with double brackets, e.g. from `[User Email]` to `[[User Email]]`. When the field is expanded and passed to the send email pipeline the additional set of brackets around the whole email, causing the `FormatException`.

The error will occur even if you just edit the message body and not even touch the recipient fields.

This is a known bug and the fix can be found in this Sitecore Knowledge base article: [Error submitting form when using Send Email action in WFFM](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/785584). Alternatively contact Sitecore Support and quote ticket number 402562.

Comment: Thanks for the details. Is there any option to import email html template in the message body? or how can we add a custom html with image/logo etc.

Comment: A templating solution does not exist out of the box unfortunately. You can switch the email message body to HTML mode and add whatever HTML you like. You might have to drag the bottom of the window down to reveal the HTML switch button though: http://imgur.com/7mi7lYj